# Django Logger: How to log Username

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I am trying to implement logging in my Django project (`django 1.11`, `Python 3.6`). I'm using default django logger.

To get the `username` in log, I have used [django-requestlogging 1.0.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-requestlogging/). 
As of now, I don't have any user other than admin superuser.

When I'm trying a GET request on front-end side, an error occurs that says `'LogSetupMiddleware' is not callable.`

1. What is the reason for this error? How do I make the logging work?
2. How do I get `AnonymousUser` in the logs?

File **settings.py** snippet:

```
INSTALLED_APPS= [
    ...
    'django_requestlogging',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django_requestlogging.middleware.LogSetupMiddleware',
    ...
]

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'standard' : {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(username)s %(request_method)s',
        }, 
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/trustcentric/django-requestlogging/src/default/django_requestlogging/middleware.py) middleware class is really not callable. To fix it you have to override that class like this:

> some/middlware/path.py

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django_requestlogging.middleware import LogSetupMiddleware as Original

class LogSetupMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin, Original):
    pass
```

And replace middleware path in settings.py by new one:

> some.middleware.path.LogSetupMiddleware

Comment: I did it but catch error ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'```. Looks like package doesn't support Python3